# Dynamic ActiveRecord finder methods chaining based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Im new to rails and I want to make a select query based on diffrent GET params (filtering and sorting). Can I some how add conditions to find in the code?

For example:

```
if params[:ratings] 
  Movie.where(:rating => params[:ratings].keys)
end
```

and then add ordering and other where conditions. How can I achive this? Maybe there is a better way to dybamicly modify select query (without making SQL string). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where`, `order`, ... methods return ActiveRecord::Relation objects so you can keep calling more query methods:

```
query = Movie
if(params[:ratings])
  query = query.where(:rating => params[:ratings].keys)
end
if(params[:some_order_param])
  query = query.order(params[:some_order_param])
end
# Keep adding more 'where', 'order', 'group', ... methods as needed ...
results = query.all
```

Comment: Ah, genius.  I had been struggling with how to get "start out" the default query, mistakenly calling `Movie.all` -- this is simple!  And to keep it all nice and tidy, one could even keep each potential filter on a single line with `query = query.order(params[:some_order_param]) if params[:some_order_param]`.  Rails is a thing of beauty and constant delight!

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually recommend the [has_scope gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) for this type of behavior. It allows you to define scopes and class methods on your models and automatically use them for filtering, ordering, etc in the controllers.

Here's a small example from the docs, but there's a lot you can do with it:

```
class Graduation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :featured, where(:featured => true)
end

class GraduationsController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :featured, :type => :boolean
end
```