# Rails 3: Building a set of filters on an index view using scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have an index view of a model which I would like to filter by some combination of the model's attributes.

For example, I have a Bill model (not the kind on ducks, the kind you have to pay) that I might filter on payee and/or status.

The model has a scope for each individual attribute, e.g.

```
scope :bill_status, lambda {|status| where("status = ?", status}
scope :bill_payee, lambda {|payee| where("payee_id = ?", payee.id}
```

The view allows the user to select *zero or more* options -- if an option is not selected, it means "don't filter by this".

In the controller, I can do something yucky like this:

```
def index
  status = params[:bill][:status]
  payee = params[:bill][:payee]
  if status.present? and payee.present?
    # chain scopes
    @bills = Bill.bill_status(status).bill_payee(payee)
  elsif status.present?
    @bills = Bill.bill_status(status)
  elsif payee.present?
    @bills = Bill.bill_payee(payee)
  else
    @bills = Bill.all
  end

  # rest of controller action
end
```

But while this works, it's neither pretty nor easily extensible -- adding a third filter means I now have many more possibilities.  I seek beauty and purity.

On the assumption that my scopes are all chainable, it seems like I should be able to do something like

```
def index
  @bills = Bill.all
  @bills = @bills.bill_status(params[:bill][:status]) if params[:bill][:status].present?
  @bills = @bills.bill_payee(params[:bill][:payee]) if params[:bill][:payee].present?

  # rest of controller code
end
```

'cept it doesn't work because `Bill.all` is an array.  Plus, that's no fun because `Bill.all` executes the query, which I only want to run once thanks to AREL magic.  Should I just define a scope like `all_bills` (with no conditions?) -- that would be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` I guess...

Is there a pattern that solves this problem more elegantly?  Whenever I have code to do one thing that relies on Model, View and Controller I feel as though I might be doing something wrong.  Or as though someone smarter and harder working than I has already solved it :-)

Bonus question: I want this all to work with my paginator of choice, the most excellent Kaminari gem.

All thoughts and ideas welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried has_scope? I just recommended this on another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820424/167614

Comment: Hi @beerlington The has_scope gem looks interesting, and its pedigree from the Platformatec crew is impeccable.  I am partial to the answer on the other thread from @mu-is-too-short, which solved a basic problem with my approach -- instead of starting with `@bills = Bill.all` I could start with `@bills = Bill` (which provides the basis for AREL scope chaining), then run the whole thing with `@bills = @bills.all` at the end.  Both solutions are great.  Now to make sure they all work with Kaminari for pagination.  Thanks both.

Comment: has_scope definitely works with will_paginate, so I'd be surprised if it didn't work with Kaminari too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I searched for solutions to what seemed like a common problem, I checked out Ryan Bates' [RailsCast and found an episode from 3 days ago on Ransack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack).  Ransack is a pretty seriously cool gem for form searching and column sorting, and I think that's the way I am going.

Thanks for the answers here -- I am glad to have learned a couple of great techniques from those who took the time and effort the answer.

Comment: An update since I asked -- I have used Ransack 0.7 and it is a brilliant bit of software, a little light on the doc but overall very elegant -- views require no special markup just names by convention for the search fields (very Railsy), one extra line in the controller, and nothing in the model.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like this:

```
proxy = Bill.scoped
if status.present?
  proxy = proxy.bill_status(status)
end
if payee.present?
  proxy = proxy.bill_payee(payee)
end

@bills = proxy
```

You can even do then some meta-programming:

```
@bills = [:status, :payee, ...].inject(Bill.scoped) do |proxy, param|
  val = params[:bill][param]
  val.present ? proxy.send("bill_#{param}", val) : proxy
end
```

Comment: Very nice :-).  Like the meta-programming solution -- a little partial with a local, and magic!